# Is it true that if an nxn matrix (A) has the rank n, then A cant be nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra

Another question:

If this nxn matrix has the rank k < n , and A^k is not the nullmatrix, then A is invertible?

Comment: An $n\times n$ matrix is invertible iff it has rank $n$. And invertible matrices are not nilpotent (except when you accept to work with $n=0$)

Comment: An $n \times n$ matrix is invertible if and only if its rank is $n$, so no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $n\geq 2$.
Title question: yes, because if $r(A) = n$ and $A^m = 0$, then $\det (A^m) = (\det (A))^m = 0$, which would contradict invertibility of $A$.

Second question: if $A$ is not of full rank, then it is automatically singular, so the implication is false.